# If Silicon was present in human body

Tags: technological-development, post-apocalypse

How human body would react and get transformed, what abilities it would have, if it had silicon in it? Let’s say, if 5% of human body consisted of silicon.

Comment: Silicon already exists in the body.  Without it, we'd die.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our bodies use silicon for bones, hair and nails etc, although significantly less than 5%, so you can expect we wouldn't be having any silicon deficiencies. Silicon is relatively chemically inert - which makes sense since it is used for breast implants and such - meaning it would likely have little effect on the body providing it is being stored somewhere that it doesn't interfere with biological processes. If it was being stored somewhere unsuitable, eg the blood, expect it to kill you or make you very ill in some manor or another

Comment: So humans exposed to breathing silicon dust will kill them? Is there a chance for humanity to survive and evolve after many-many years of exposure?

Comment: Expect silicon dust to be much more harmful than macroscopic pieces, they will manage to disperse to vulnerable areas of the body easier. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicosis, it appears inhalation would kill you in the quantities you're talking about. I found a data sheet on silicon safety. sciencelab.com/msds.php?msdsId=9924921. 
Re evolving, humanity will only have a chance to evolve if some people possess a mutation making their lungs silicon-resistant (very unlikely imo). If you're talking about a sci-fi world, you could work your way around this with genetic engineering

Comment: Silicosis happens because you are basically breathing in microscopic razor blades that shred your lung cells leading to the development of scar tissue, which you can't breath with.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to some not-really-scientific research Silicon seems to accumulate on the bones, helping them get stronger and prevent osteoporosis.